# Generic Type Aliases w.r.t. Generic Class Parameter

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

According to https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-type-aliases mypy supports using a generic `TypeVar` in an type alias, e.g.

```
T = TypeVar("T")
Alias = Tuple[int, T]
def f(t: T) -> Alias[T]:
    return (1, t)
f('x')
```

I wondered if this extended to classes.  Specifically, to help with this pattern:

```
T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")
V = TypeVar("V")
W = TypeVar("W")

class Bar(Generic[T, U, V]): ...

class Foo(Generic[T, U, V, W]):
    def do_something(self, x: Bar[T, U, V], y: W) -> Bar[T, U, V]:
        reveal_type(x)  # note: Revealed type is "Bar[T`1, U`2, V`3]"
```

A bit contrived, but the point is, `Foo` performs lots of operations on a highly parametrized `Bar` and it would be nice to not have to repeat `Bar[T, U , V]` everywhere (especially because in the real code the TypeVars have long names).

I tried making a `ClassVar[TypeAlias]`, but I don't think this actually worked and just substituted `Any`, and I only see examples for functions in the linked mypy docs:

```
class Foo(Generic[T, U, V, W]):
    BarType: ClassVar[TypeAlias] = Bar[T, U, V]  # Had hoped this would work, but seems to evaluate to just be `Any`
    def do_something(self, x: BarType) -> BarType:
        reveal_type(x)  # note: Revealed type is "Any"
```

I also tried using an intermediate TypeVar:

```
BarType = TypeVar("BarType", bound=Bar[Any, Any, Any])
class Foo(Generic[BarType, W]):
    def do_something(self, x: BarType, y: W) -> BarType:
        reveal_type(x)  # BarType
```

But I had some issues discussed here [Genericizing a class using a TypeVar with a bound from another generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72842356/genericizing-a-class-using-a-typevar-with-a-bound-from-another-generic-class) so I am still unsure if this is the way to go.  Furthermore, in the real life code, `Foo` actually needs access to the individual parameters of `Bar`, so the class signature would need to be (I assume):

```
class Foo(Generic[T, U, V, BarType, W]): ...
```

which would make instantiating the class look a bit weird, e.g.,

```
Foo[int, int, str, Bar[int, int, str], float]
```

and it's not clear to me yet whether mypy would catch inconsistencies in the two groupings of the parameters `T, U, V`.

Comment: It's been a year and there aren't any answers on this.  Did you find a good answer elsewhere?